# AWS Fargate/.NET Core issue with running container

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-fargate

I'm trying to run docker container (ASP.NET Core 2.1) in fargate and constantly I'm getting following error:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (XXX.deps.json) was not found:
2018-09-03 22:10:16 package: 'AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs', version: '3.3.4.10'
package: 'AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs', version: '3.3.4.10'
2018-09-03 22:10:16 path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs.dll'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs.dll'
```

I did not have this library in my dependencies, however after adding it, it is still causing issues.

I'm using following build:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS base
...
RUN dotnet build XXX/XXX.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 -o /app
```

Looking into other issues, I found as popular solution:

```
    <PropertyGroup>   
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

however it does not work for my issue.

I will much appreciate each suggestion.

Comment: I found the reason after few hours more of digging - I enabled in task definition logging with cloudwatch, however now I'm getting error 140

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the container itself. It was not built properly due to dependencies, plus folders has same naming (root folder and main subfolder).